# I was trying to install youtube down loader in ubuntu 16 and it is not getting install

Tags: 16.04

```
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  google-chrome-stable : Depends: libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0) but it is      not going to be installed
                    Depends: libappindicator1 but it is not going to be installed
  youtube-dl : Depends: python-pkg-resources but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: ffmpeg or
                      libav-tools but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: mpv or
                      mplayer or
                      mplayer2 but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: rtmpdump but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Have you tried the suggested `apt-get -f install`?

Comment: yes but it says
apt-get -f install    ................         
    E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission      denied)              ................           
      E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Comment: You will need to run it as root. Do `sudo apt-get -f install`